# Анализ кода phpstan-ом

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Имеется проект на PHP 7.4.

Анализ моего кода [phpstan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan)-ом

```
./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse --paths-file=./phpstan.dist --level=max
```

приводит к ошибке

```
 ------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Line   src/Service/Twig/TwigExtension.php                                     
 ------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  37     Parameter #2 $callable of class Twig\TwigFilter constructor expects    
         (callable(): mixed)|null, array(mixed, 'translate') given. 
 ------ -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Проблемный код:

```
...
$this->twig->addFilter(
    new \Twig\TwigFilter(
        TranslatorTwigFilter::NAME,
        [$this->container->get(TranslatorTwigFilter::class), 'translate'],
    )
);
...
```

Пишу по инструкции с официального сайта.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с ситуацией.

Класс целиком:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Service\Translator;

class TranslatorTwigFilter
{
    public const NAME = 'trans';
    private TranslatorInterface $translator;

    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public function translate(string $code, ?string $lang = null): string
    {
        return $lang
            ? $this->translator->translate($code, $lang)
            : $this->translator->translate($code)
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: А у вас есть метод `translate`? Выложите весь класс

Comment: Добавил код класса.  Но, мне кажется, что необходимо как-то правильно передать 2 аргумент как callable(), а не как массив.

Comment: Попробуйте это new \Twig\TwigFilter(
        'translatorFilter',
        [TranslatorTwigFilter::class, 'translate'],
    )

Comment: Да, действительно всё так, но пришлось менять некоторую логику приложения. Большое спасибо!